# How do you do data augmentation for segmentation in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, data-augmentation

I am trying to add augmentation to my data loader in torch. All of my example images have masks and none are blank. But when I add an augmentation like `RandomRotation` I find that some examples in my dataset then yield an image that has not labels anymore and things fall apart.

Is there a way to correctly handle this in PyTorch. Here as example of the problem?

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
      # load image and mask
      img_path = os.path.join(self.root, self.imagefolder, self.imgs[idx])
      mask_path = os.path.join(self.root, self.maskfolder , self.masks[idx])
      img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")

      # The problem is that augmentation could remove all the visible labels here
      img, mask = run_augmentations(img, mask)
      
      mask = Image.open(mask_path)
      mask = np.array(mask)
      obj_ids = np.unique(mask)
      obj_ids = obj_ids[1:]

      masks = mask == obj_ids[:, None, None]
      num_objs = len(obj_ids)
      boxes = []

      for i in range(num_objs):
          pos = np.where(masks[i])

          xmin = np.min(pos[1])
          xmax = np.max(pos[1])
          ymin = np.min(pos[0])
          ymax = np.max(pos[0])


          if xmin == xmax or ymin == ymax:
              print("WARNING ZERO SIZE BOUNDING BOX AFTER AUGMENTATION")
              print(img_path)
          
          boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

      if len(boxes) == 0:
          print("WARNING ZERO BOUNDING BOXES AFTER AUGMENTATION")
          print(img_path)

      ...
```

EDIT: My best attempt if that if there are no labels after augmentation return the image and mask without any augmentation.

Comment: What even is your `run_augmentations` function? Some functions might use interpolation and that can mess up discrete labels.

Comment: @hkchengrex It's just `torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation(180)`

Comment: Try adding `resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST` to `RandomRotation`?